# What is the difference between "He has finished" and "He have finished"?

Tags: phrase-usage, difference

What is the difference between "he has finished" and "he have finished"?

Comment: Asking on a Q&A site isn't the right way to find out how to conjugate a word.  You need to find a book or webpage which tells you how to do it.  I'm honestly not sure which resource to recommend, but for now this will work: http://conjugation.com/verb/have See what it says?  *"I have; you have; he/she/it has; we have; you have; they have"*.  As you can see, **"He have"* is incorrect.

Comment: I suspect the OP may have seen something like "could he have finished the job already?" where "he have finished" is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: I don't get why this question is at -1 and snailboat's comment is at +6 right now. Am I wrong for thinking this is a valid question for someone who is learning English and an appropriate question for this site?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I disagree with the other answers so far given.  "He has finished" is present perfect as has been stated.  However, "he have finished" is the present perfect subjunctive, which although rare is perfectly correct.  For example, "It is necessary that he have finished two years of music theory before getting his degree."

Comment: The original question capitalized *He* in both quotes.  Someone edited it since then to remove the capitalization, so it's no longer clear that the OP was asking about usage specifically at the beginning of a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*Have* is used with plural things and with I and you.
*Has* is used with singular things excluding I and you.

Answer (score 1):

"He has finished" is grammatical. "He have finished" is not.

Answer (score 0):

The first phrase is using the Present Perfect, while the second phrase is not standard English.

The second phrase would use the Future Perfect, if it were "he **will** have finished." Often, *will* is written *'ll*, so you can also find "he'll have finished."